# Android WebView disable suggestions for input

Tags: android, android-webview

I am creating `InputMethodManager` to show soft keyboard for a webview.

```
InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
manager.showSoftInput(webview, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Is there a way to disable auto completion for the soft keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Try `webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);`

Comment: I am not using EditText. I have webview with input field

Comment: try webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);

Comment: I didn't meant to disable form data! I have android 4.2 and when I write something the keyboard shows some sugestions. I would like to disable that. If I had EditText I could use `android:inputType="textFilter" ` but I don't know how to fix this using InputManager